# jQuery - Multiple separate var formData = { POST Form Data Calls (I Want to make independent call one per one)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I Want to make independent call one per one, I want to make separate Form Data jobs one per one, each independent call and with different data, The problem is that a single call is made and this would be the First Call:

```
var formData = { // First job
  "Phone": "999999999"
};
$.post('http://localhost/', formData)
  .done (showResult)
  .fail(showError);
}
var formData = { // Second job
  "Phone": "888888888"
};
$.post('http://localhost/', formData)
  .done (showResult)
  .fail(showError);
```

Only first job successfully.

Comment: does it give any error in console ?

Comment: Why you close with a function bracket near .fail(showError);
} . I think it is unexpected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was that curly bracket in your code (after your `$.post` call) that broke it. Below you find a slightly edited and working version of your code:

```js
function show(type){
 return function(d){console.log(type,d)}}
var formData={Phone:"999999999"};
$.post('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', formData)
  .done(show('result'))
  .fail(show('fail'));

var formData={Phone:"888888888"};
$.post('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', formData)
  .done(show('result'))
  .fail(show('fail'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

It it *not* a good idea to write it in this way ( repeated code etc.) but it does work.

Answer (score 1):

```
/* By putting the data into an array, we achieve some important advantages:
 *
 *   1) We can use javascript's powerful array methods to manage the data.
 *   2) We have abstracted the definition of the data away so that we could replace it with
 *        any other data source that returns a compatible array.
 *
 */
const phones = ['999999999', '888888888']


/*
 *  Putting this function on its own allows for better maintainability by allowing it to call different
 *  urls with different data. Ideally, you would also supply success and error callbacks, but I didn't
 *  want to complicate the example.
 */
const doPost = (url, data) => {
    $.post(url, data)
        .done(res => {console.log(res})
        .fail(err => {console.log(err})
}

/*
 * Here I'm using one of the array methods that I mentioned earlier, Array.forEach. This
 * function runs the supplied function once for each element in the array, so the first time 
 *  phone==="999999999" and the second time phone==="888888888".
 *
 * Since it's called for each element, doPost will be called twice in this example.
 * 
 * I used async/await to force the first function to complete before executing the next one.
 * This might not actually be necessary, but since you say that your backend is "swallowing"
 * the calls, I figured it was worth a try. Ultimately, though, you really want to find a way to do
 * this more efficiently and in a non-blocking way.
 */
phones.forEach(async phone => await doPost('http://localhost/', {Phone: phone}))
```

Comment: thank you but, i need to make independent call one per one

Comment: That's what this does. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: @DanielGonzalez: I'm adding more explanation to my answer for you.